# Richfaces 4, a4j:command render another h:form

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, seam2

How does `a4j:commandLink` in `dataTable` render `UI Component` of another `h:form`?
In `tableForm`, when I click edit `a4j:commandLink` of department `datatable`, `ajax` cannot render the `entryForm` of department.
I also try to use `ajax:region` it doesn't work and doesn't show anything error.I don't know why.

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    template="/layout/adminTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form id="entryForm">
            <h:outputText value="Edit Department" styleClass="subTitle"/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Name : " styleClass="inputLabel"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{ManageDepartmentAction.department.name}" styleClass="inputText"/>

                <h:outputText value="Description : " styleClass="inputLabel"/>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{ManageDepartmentAction.department.description}" cols="50" rows="6"/>      
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton id="editBtn" value="Edit"  action="#{ManageDepartmentAction.editDepartment}"/>     
        </h:form> <br/>
        <h:form id="tableForm">
            <rich:dataTable value="#{ManageDepartmentAction.departmentList}" var="dep" id="departmentTable"
                            style="width:100%" rowKeyVar="index">
                <rich:column sortBy="#{dep.id}" style="width:200px;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Department ID"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{dep.id}" styleClass="tableContent"/>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column sortBy="#{dep.name}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{dep.name}" styleClass="tableContent"/>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column sortBy="#{dep.description}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Description"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{dep.description}" styleClass="tableContent"/>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column style="width:100px;text-align:center;">
                    <a4j:commandLink value="Edit-1" action="#{ManageDepartmentAction.prepareEditDepartment(dep)}" render="entryForm"/>

                    <a4j:commandLink value="Edit-2" action="#{ManageDepartmentAction.prepareEditDepartment(dep)}" render=":entryForm"/>

                    <a4j:commandLink value="Edit-3" action="#{ManageDepartmentAction.prepareEditDepartment(dep)}" render="tableForm :entryForm"/>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

@Scope(CONVERSATION)
@Name("ManageDepartmentAction")
public class ManageDepartmentAction {

    public List<Department> departmentList;

    @In("#{DepartmentService}")
    private IDepartmentService departmentService;

    @Out(value = "department", required = false)
    private Department department;

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public boolean isCreateNew() {
        return createNew;
    }

    @Begin(nested = true)
    public void init() {
        departmentList = departmentService.findAllDepartments();
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartmentList() {
        return departmentList;
    }

    public void prepareEditDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void editDepartment() {
        System.out.println("Edit Department Name : " + department.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using attribute render="@all". Please verify using firebug whether rendered id of form is "entryForm" only or it has some JSF prefix added to it. That might be the cause render="entryForm" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the full id of the controls you want to render with ajax. A basic example:

```html
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText id="txtSomeName" value="#{bean.name}" />
    <a4j:commandButton value="Click me" render=":form2:txtName" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="form2">
    <h:inputText id="txtName" value="#{bean.name}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I would like render whole `h:form`, like `:form2`. `<a4j:commamdButton>` or `<a4j:commandLink>` must be in the `DataTable`.